# Java Layout Managers

Tags: java, resize, layout-manager

What are the benefits of using an existing layout manager as opposed writing a listener that handles resizing functions? For instance, I needed to arrange buttons in a grid and center the grid:

```
int h = component.getHeight() / 11;
int w = component.getWidth() / 9;
int offsetX = w;
int offsetY = h;
int x = (2 * column) * w - offsetX;
int y = (2 * row) * h - offsetY;

setBounds(x, y, w, h);
```

Instead of fumbling around with a layout manager I wrote this small bit of code that is activated for the buttons whenever the JPanel is resized. If I were to use a layout manager, it would be more cumbersome to write the code to arrange everything and if I were to say add a component to the JPanel, things would get even more complex as opposed to simply adding a few additions or subtractions.

So given this, would there be any benefits to using a layout manager in a situation as this or would a few customized lines be easier to use and maintain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is basically mimicking a [`GridLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 9));
// add all the components
...
// Profit
```

To center it:

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
outerPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Alright, there are maybe 5 lines of code extra in my implementation but are there any real benefits to this method as opposed to my code? Speed? File Size?

Comment: @Glenn, your code is specific to your implementation.  It is not an extensible solution.  Also, the GirdLayout method is all taken care of in the set up.  No special event handling code necessary.  Also, your way is very non-standard.

Comment: @Glenn, also, since Java is dong the resizing, I'd assume its a little speedier, but I can't guarantee that.

Comment: I understand the non-extensible and I'm quite fine with it. There is nothing more to be put on the UI and I know this for a fact. However what is 'non-standard' about it? Is it simply the fact that a layout manager is not involved or is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: @Glenn, also, the intention of the layout is much more clear when it is set in a constructor.  It would be difficult to tell what you are doing at first.  It is unintuitive to go look at a resize event to see how you are laying out your components.

Comment: @Glenn, there is nothing wrong with it.  But, it is better to let Java handle the layout when you can.  It leaves you time for other, more important, tasks.

Comment: @jjnguy Well that is what I was looking to know. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that for something so simple, writing your own code is easy enough.  But what will happen when you find out you need to add two new buttons and a text area?  I think learning to use the Layout Managers is a good investment of your time, since the knowledge will allow you to scale your GUI's complexity easily.  (No pun intended ;)

Comment: Thing is, in this example it is a Jeopardy style game so there will only be buttons in the area. I have a slot for scoring and that is that. There isn't a chance of new components coming into play.

Answer (score 1):

Cool. Now try to write the same 128 times (for each control on each screen). And it is not the end of the game. Now try to change graphic design your application, i.e. rewrite this code 128 times again. Enjoy!

Comment: I have a button repeated 20 times, it is part of a class that extends the JButton class. Its not that miserable ;)